# AWS Lambda Python Package Layer

Tags: python, aws-lambda, pip

I need to use the package `Brotli` in a Lambda function, so I'm trying to add it to a layer. I took the following steps:

Launch x86 EC2 instance

```
mkdir layer
cd layer
pip install --target ./package brotli
cd ./package
zip -r ../package.zip .
```

Verify that `package.zip` contains brotli with `unzip -l package.zip`

Upload to S3

Create layer from S3 object

Run Lambda function that calls `import brotli`

I get the following error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named '_brotli'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "requestId": "9e09618c-4eaa-41a5-8926-0c18f78f87d7",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

Tried:

- Follow the same steps with a different dependency. This worked and I was able to import that package.
- Run the lambda handler (which imports Brotli) locally. I did not get an error.

Expecting:
No error

Comment: You associated the layer with the function, right?

Comment: Make sure that your installed package (brotli) is for the python version that your lambda is running.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I got the same error when I included the brotli module in the deployment package. This error is due to a compatibility issue between the python package containing the compiled code or the Lambda Layer and the Lambda runtime. Try installing the brotli module according to the instructions in the following documentation.

https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/lambda-python-package-compatible

Make sure the .so file included in the deployment package or Lambda Layer is in the following format

`_brotli.cpython-{your_function_python_version}-{architecture}-linux-gnu.so`.

For example, if you are using python 3.9 and your Lambda architecture is x86_64, the .so file would be named

`_brotli.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`.

I hope my answer will help you to solve your problem.